# 4-pin jack works on mac - with splitter it works on mac but not on windows

Tags: windows-7, microphone, headphone-jack

I have a problem with my mic on windows and I will be really gratefull if you could help me to solve it.

Some times ago I bought an AKG Q460, I'm using it with my smartphone and with my MBP, and it's working as well.

Recently I bought a [4 pin to 2 * 3 pin splitter](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=945088&Q=&is=REG&A=details) to use it on my windows desktop computer. (I read [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/700707/can-windows-use-headsets-that-have-a-single-audio-jack-with-4-rings) before).

And so it's not working, I thought about a broken product so I made tests on a mac with 2 * 3 pin jack in and it's working on mac os x but not on windows 7!

So I'm just wondering what is going on, why it's not working on windows and how to fix it.
For tests on windows I configured as well as a normal microphone, with full pre-ampli and sounds max.
Also, a usual microphone works on windows...

I heard something when I'm pushing the button on the cable (the one to answer a call), that's a noise like a *tching* of a cash register imitated by a robot voice (yeah I'm sorry but I can't be more precise :s).

Thanks you if you can help me, cause I really don't know how to fix this...

EDIT : My windows 7 pc mb is an asrock z87e-itx.

Answer (score 1):

Description is not clear enough. When connected everything is working? Or is it just mic not detected? Or detected and not working?
Mac and windows on the same machine?

Swap jacks on the 2*3 end between ports. Usually the ports autodetect source, so if you cannot hear anything when connecting to the ports, no autodetect and need to plug correct jacks into correct ports.
Also: front or rear ports? If front then mic-mic and headphone-headphone connections are crucial.

If that doesn't help, try to update drivers.

From comment I can definitely say it's not hardware related. So, that being the case, Windows is the obvious problem. You need to pinpoint more accurately where it is happening. Did you follow the instructions in the link I provided?

Comment: The mic is detected but windows does not receive sounds. Yes mac and windows on the same machine. I tried to swap ports it does nothing. Front port or rear ports are the same results. I have last driver installed.

That is why I don't really understand what is going on...
Everything is working on os x but the mic is not transmit sounds on windows 7 even if my drivers are the latest...

Could it be microphone-related ? My old microphone is still working on this computer's Windows..

Comment: Then only thing left is this:
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=uk&lc=en&docname=c01926155

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of forums etc. to try and fix this, but as it stand you will have to use a usb to 4 pin 3.5mm jack adapter because Apple have not updated the drivers to support 4 pin headsets under boot camp.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3369017?start=15&tstart=0